# How do I organize my Java Eclipse project so that the user then only needs to do one import?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I organize my Java Eclipse project so that the user then only needs to do one import?

I am working on a graphics library and I have various package in it like graphics.A, graphics.B, etc. but when I give this library to the user I want him to be able to use
it just by saying import graphics for example. I am not sure how to do that. The way I have it
now he would have to do import graphics.A.*, import graphics.B.*, etc.

Thanks

Comment: I guess `import graphics.*;` is out of the discussion, right?

Comment: @Slanec That does seem to be the first solution that comes to mind.

Comment: Why?  Eclipse creates the import statements for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, tooling should take care of managing the imports.  I'm not sure why having a single import is of any importance, but I can't know your motivations, so I'll just accept it.

- Put all your classes in a single package.  (not recommended at all.)
- Create a broker class that, once instantiated, reaches into the package hierarchy and instantiates everything for you and returns Object instances, or some root type of your design.  (not recommended at all.)
- Assume your developers have tooling which can manage the imports for them and don't worry about it.  (Recommended.)

Answer (score 5):

Importing all subpackages with single line is impossible in Java.

```
import graphics.*;
```

would import only classes in `graphics`, `graphics.A` and `graphics.B` would not be imported, if `A` and `B` are subpackages.

So either put all your classes in one subpackage, or user would have to import more than once like

```
import graphics.A.*;
import graphics.B.*;
```